# Error while trying to build an anchor project

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

[image: error screenshot]I am trying to build a new anchor project with boilerplate code. However, I am failing to do so and getting the error: error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable

Anchor version: 0.27.0
OS: macOS Ventura 13.0

Comment: Please have a look at https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7115

Answer (score 1):

Can you try specifying your dependencies like this:

```
[dependencies]
         anchor-lang = "0.26.0"
         anchor-spl = "0.26.0"
         metaplex-token-metadata = { version = "0.0.1", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }
         solana-program = "=1.14.13"
         getrandom = { version = "0.2.9", features = ["custom"] }
         switchboard-v2 = "0.1.15"
         mpl-bubblegum = { version = "0.8.0", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ]}
         spl-account-compression = { version = "0.1.10", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ]}
```

Just remove whatever deps you do not need from the above. [Source](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/32133#issuecomment-1601242807) and a [link](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/32133) to the full discussion on the Solana gh issues page.